# Cake Build - How to Invoke other Cake Build Scripts from another Cake Build Script

Tags: c#, cakebuild

If I have a large code-base with many inter-dependent projects, for example, `projects/A`, `projects/B`, and `projects/C`, where `A` requires `B`, and `B` requires `C`, and each of these projects has a Cake build script, for example, `projects/A/build.cake`, `projects/B/build.cake`, and `projects/C/build.cake`, what is the best way to write the `projects/A/build.cake` such that it invokes the Cake build `projects/B/build.cake` as a dependency task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion would be to keep each projects build.cake file isolated, only working/building that project. Then, I would have another, higher level build script which then used to run:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.Cake/CakeAliases/5FCD85B6

To invoke the project build scripts in the order that they are required.

You could have something like:

```
CakeExecuteScript("./projects/C/build.cake");
CakeExecuteScript("./projects/B/build.cake");    
CakeExecuteScript("./projects/A/build.cake");
```

Obviously, you could wrap each of those in a try/catch to take action to stop the overall build, if one of the project builds fail.